# Is there a way to start SSMS and autoconnect to different servers?

Tags: ssms, ssms-2016

Is there a way to start SSMS 2016 and autoconnect to different servers? So that I don't have to do this manually every time I start SSMS. An SSMS add-on?

Answer (score 0):

From what i can tell start SSMS.exe with parameters should do the trick. For example:

```
SSMS.exe -S localhost -D master -E
```

This will start SSMS and connect to master database of default instance using Windows authentication.

For more information, please check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162825%28v=sql.130%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Thanks.. However I want to connect to a multitude of different servers all at the same time. Connecting to one server manually is not really an issue for me. I want to start SSMS and it connects to all the servers I connected in my last session, and better yet, reopens the tabs which were open in the last session.